# Deep Link in kotlin/java android

Tags: android, firebase

I have 2 Application with same server and I Have 2 Different Deep link for both but both deep link opens only one application. If First Application is not available in device then after it will open link in their correct application.
I Have adde3d **assestslink.json** file for both with correct SHA key , add data and all in manifest file also. What I missed here?